# Is there a version limit in GridFS?

Tags: mongodb, versioning, gridfs

In mongodb GridFS when you insert a file with the same name as an already existing file the old file becomes a previous version of the new file.

I'm wondering can I do this multiple times and is there a limit?

For example, I have a file `file.txt`, then I insert another `file.txt`, now I have two versions of `file.txt`. I now insert a third `file.txt`. Do I now have three versions of the file? Or just two? How many more times can I insert `file.txt` and keep all the previous versions?

Finally, how do I access these previous versions or overwrite them?

Comment: gridfs by default behaviour, unless you have a specific driver that does just that, does not version but instead overwrites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in limit on the number of versions, but it may be that a particular driver may set some limit.

As for getting a specific version, are you by any chance using a specific driver?  For instance, I believe pyMongo has a get_version() api which allows you to specify a particular version of the file.

As for replacing files, if you're running mongofiles utility in the shell, you can specify -r to replace a document -- such as mongofiles -r put file.txt -- which would leave you with just this version of file.txt.  There may be different implementation with specific drivers.

Regards,

Kay

Comment: Hi @Kay, sorry I didn't make that clear, yes, I will be using `pymongo` and with regards to replacing a document, what I meant was replacing a particular version of that document, so for example the only replacing the second `file.txt`.

Comment: Hi @toofarsideways -- unfortunately, I don't believe you can swap out earlier versions.